# Dictionary of dictionaries updates all keys simultaneously

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dataset of paired sentences (a sentence in English and its translation to German). Suppose I have WORD1, which is a word in English. I'm trying to know what German words (and how many times) appear in a German sentence that is in a pair where WORD1 appears in the English sentence. I need to do this for every English word available (I have a list of the English words). To do it, I have created a dictionary, where keys are all English words and values are a dictionary, that is empty at the beginning and that I want to update to add all German words that co-appear in a pair with that English word.

The code I did is:

```
print('Building English dictionary...')
d = dict.fromkeys(words_english, {})

print('Start iterating over samples...')
for sentence_german, sentence_english in zip(data_german, data_english):
    sentence_german = sentence_german.split()
    sentence_english = sentence_english.split()
    for word in sentence_english:
        update_dict(word, sentence_german, d)
```

Where the function update_dict is:

```
def update_dict(w, sentence, d):
    if sentence:
        for paired_word in sentence:
            if paired_word in d[w].keys():
                d[w][paired_word] = d[w][paired_word] + 1
            else:
                d[w][paired_word] = 1
```

However, this code is not working as I expected. Every time that the function update_dict is called, all the values of d are updated simultaneously. For example, if I execute this code (same one as before but with prints and breaking the loops for simplification):

```
print('Building English dictionary...')
d = dict.fromkeys(words_english, {})

print('Start iterating over samples...')
for sentence_german, sentence_english in zip(data_german, data_english):
    sentence_german = sentence_german.split()
    sentence_english = sentence_english.split()
    for word in sentence_english:
        print('WORD', word)
        print(sentence_german)
        update_dict(word, sentence_german, d)
    break
break
```

The output is:

```
WORD we
['wir', 'glauben', 'nicht', ',', 'daß', 'wir', 'nur', 'ro', 's', 'inen', 'her', 'au', 'sp', 'ick', 'en', 'sollten', '.']
```

But dictionary d now has this:

```
{'wir': 2, 'glauben': 1, 'nicht': 1, ',': 1, 'daß': 1, 'nur': 1, 'ro': 1, 's': 1, 'inen': 1, 'her': 1, 'au': 1, 'sp': 1, 'ick': 1, 'en': 1, 'sollten': 1, '.': 1}
```

in all of its values. Why did words that are not "we" update?

I also tried to use a different implementation of update_dict (the one below) but the same problem keeps happening.

```
def update_dict(w, sentence, d):
    if sentence:
        for paired_word in sentence:
            if paired_word in d[w].keys():
                d[w].update({paired_word:(d[w][paired_word]+1)})
            else:
                d[w].update({paired_word:1})
```

Why are all the keys (English words) updated if the value of w is just "we"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because

```
d = dict.fromkeys(words_english, {})
```

uses the same `{}` for all keys. (`fromkeys` is generally more useful when the value is not mutable.)

Use a dictionary comprehension, á la

```
d = {word: {} for word in words_english}
```

instead to have a separate dict for each key.

Even better, since you're counting occurrences, use our good friends `defaultdict` and `Counter` from the `collections` module, like

```
import collections

d = collections.defaultdict(collections.Counter)
```

and you can just do

```
d[w][paired_word] += 1
```

without any `if in`/`update` shenanigans, and you don't need to even know the `words_english` in advance.